# How do I whitelist an index.php file in cpanel CSF csf.pignore to disable the "excessive resource usage" alerts?

Tags: cpanel

ConfigServer Firewall in cPanel (CSF) sends me a hundred emails a day saying that I have "excessive resource usage" for a file which I am aware of but it is OK to have high usage for that user.

This is intolerable.

Here is one such example:

[SUBJECT]

```
lfd on server1.evx.ca: Excessive resource usage: myuser (21046 (Parent PID:21014))
```

[EMAIL]

```
Time:         Wed Nov  2 14:23:36 2016 -0700
Account:      myuser
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     1819 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/bin/php
Command Line: /usr/bin/php /mnt/home2/myuser/public_html/mywebsite.com/index.php
PID:          21046 (Parent PID:21014)
Killed:       No
```

I had already added it to the whitelist months ago, but still I continue getting the emails every day adding up to hundreds of thousands of emails. I am sick of it.

Here is what I have in my whitelist currently:

file: `/etc/csf/csf.pignore`

```
exe:/mnt/home2/myuser/public_html/mywebsite.com/index.php
```

Of course, I have restarted CSF numerous times in the past few months.

Why isn't this working, and how can I get it working?

Comment: Have you tried whitelisting the entire user?

Comment: That is a TERRIBLE suggestion! Basically you are telling me to turn off the firewall? No way!

Comment: No, since you already whitelisted the file but that didn't work, I suggested you could try whitelisting the user to check if the notifications are still sent. Obviously you don't want to disable the excessive usage notifications or CSF entirely.

Comment: No way! I am not turning off my server firewall (not for one or any user)!

Comment: I don't suggest you should disable it permanently, just for a short time (maybe an hour?) just to see if csf even respects your ignore rules or not.

Comment: No, I will not disable my firewall on my server for any length of time.

Comment: You won't be disabling the firewall, just the excessive usage checks for a single user (who you've obviously already vetted since you state the file is OK to exceed these limits)

Comment: ? Your suggestion was "whitelist the entire user". You ask asking me to turn off the firewall for the whole user. Terrible! Never do that guys!

Comment: I'm asking you to whitelist the user in one *specific* check. Surely you have your firewall setup properly so that a user can't suddenly break everything if you disable one check. If you're paranoid you can always monitor their processes from your terminal while they are whitelisted to ensure they're not doing anything malicious. Furthermore, I assume you're not reading all the notifications about them anyway, so whitelisting them from the notifications will only reduce noise without giving them more access.

Comment: I am not going to whitelist the whole user. That is not an acceptable option.

Comment: Obviously it won't be a permanent solution.. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Not even a temporary solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `exe:/mnt/home2/myuser/public_html/mywebsite.com/index.php` to the process ignore list won't help because the `exe:` command only ignores executables.

As you can see in the notification email:

```
Executable:   /usr/bin/php
Command Line: /usr/bin/php /mnt/home2/myuser/public_html/mywebsite.com/index.php
```

The executable is `/usr/bin/php`, which you should not whitelist because it would ignore all of PHP.

Instead, try adding the following line:

```
cmd:/usr/bin/php /mnt/home2/myuser/public_html/mywebsite.com/index.php
```

This should properly ignore all php processes executing that specific file.

Another thing you could try is

```
pcmd:*/mnt/home2/myuser/public_html/mywebsite.com/index.php
```

This will ignore all commands ending in the path of the file, which includes php processes.

Comment: I see! I will try this when I get a chance. This may be the answer! Thanks for your answer :) If it works, I will accept.

Comment: Just want to update and let you know I have implemented this just now. I will ket you know if it works. If so then I will accept the solution.

Comment: Appears to have worked, no more notifications so far today from the whitelisted lines.

Answer (score -1):

try to put "exe:/usr/bin/php" without quotes in file: /etc/csf/csf.pignore

Comment: Wouldn’t this whitelist *all* PHP?   Are you saying that it’s impossible to whitelist a single PHP file; you have to whitelist the entire website?   And do you *know* that this will work, or are you just guessing?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott Yes it would whitelist all PHP which is very terrible advice, thanks for pointing that out.